# Laravel - How to paginate here?

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I have this code and I want to paginate $shares.

How can I archive this?

```
$level = Share::join('follows', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'follows.user_id')
         ->where('follows.follower_id', Auth::user()->id)
         ->where('follows.level', 1)
         ->get(array('shares.*'));
//get 10% of shares
$count = Share::count()/10;
$count = round($count);
$top10 = Share::orderBy('positive', 'DESC')
         ->take($count)
         ->get();
$shares = $top10->merge($level);
//get only unique from shares
$unique = array();
$uniqueShares = $shares->filter(function($item) use (&$unique) {
    if (!in_array($item->id, $unique)) {
        $unique[] = $item->id;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
//order by id
$shares = $uniqueShares->sortBy(function($share)
{
    return -($share->id);
});
return View::make('layout/main')
->with('shares', $shares);
```

Answer (score 1):

lots of reudandant unnecessary codes here.

**1st:**

```
$level = Share::join('follows', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'follows.user_id')
     ->where('follows.follower_id', Auth::user()->id)
     ->where('follows.level', 1)
     ->get(array('shares.*'));
```

Why you are taking **ALL** the records only to discard it later?

**2nd:**

`$shares = $top10->merge($level);` Why you are merging the two arrays?

**3rd:**

```
$uniqueShares = $shares->filter(function($item) use (&$unique) {
if (!in_array($item->id, $unique)) {
    $unique[] = $item->id;
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

});

You **HAD** to wrote this snippet because above in *2nd*, you merged the two arrays which will yield duplicated entries. So why **merging**?

**4th:**

```
//order by id
$shares = $uniqueShares->sortBy(function($share)
{
    return -($share->id);
});
```

And here comes the actual data which you actually want.

So let's **recape**

You need

- 10% of total shares
- order by some `positive` column
- order by amount of shares perhaps as i am guessing.

To use the inbuilt `paginate()`, you'l need `paginate()` that's a must.

Rest is simple.

1. count the total result. `round(Share::count()/10)`
2. put it in `paginate()` as the 1st arguement.
3. Add the order by clause whichever is necessary.
4. looking at the code, it doesn't look like you will/should have duplicated data which may haved added the `distinct` and `group by` clause.

use `remember` in `Share::count()/10;` to Cache it. You don't need to run the query over and over again.

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are merging your queries you may need to manually create it the pagination in your blade, then send a variable to "take" the next set you want.

Read the Laravel Docs for more info on implementing it into your views and manually creating it.
http://laravel.com/docs/pagination

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should be good to go

```
Share::join('follows', 'shares.user_id', '=', 'follows.user_id')
            ->where('follows.follower_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('follows.level', 1)
            ->paginate(20);
```

Maybe you would like to specify columns to select in `select()` method.